# Django model method vs custom manager

Tags: django, orm, model

I am having trouble deciding between using a custom manager or a model method. I have a model `User` and have a query to find other users within a specific user's radius.

So my two options are:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def find_users_in_radius(self, user):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            location__distance_lt=(
                user.location, Distance(mi=user.search_radius))).exclude(
            pk=user.pk)

class User(AbstractUser):
    .....
    users_in_radius = UserManager()
```

or a method on the `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    .....
    def users_in_search_radius(self):
        return User.objects.filter(
            location__distance_lt=(
                self.location, Distance(mi=self.search_radius))).exclude(
            pk=self.pk)
```

In my view I would then get query results using either the first method: `User.users_in_radius.find_users_in_radius(request.user)`

or the second method: `request.user.users_in_search_radius()`.

I like the second option better but I am wondering if this is bad practice. I haven't seen any examples of people calling `User.objects` in a model method. Is there another way to do this or is the custom manager a better approach?

Comment: I don't see any problem with 2nd option. its much more convenient and using `objects` is not a problem in a model method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case specifically, you should go with the non-manager version, if you go with the custom manager you'll be adding a method as well (not working over the manager QuerySet), and also you will have to provide the user parameter.

Using a method left the user instance the responsibility of finding users nears to itself.

And not to mention you have to write more code using the first option and it would be slower too.

```
user.user_in_radiuos.find_users_in_radius(user)  # Two attribute lookpus, redundance: calling object == parameter.
user.users_in_search_radius()  # Clean, no redundance.
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to define a custom manager when you want to modify the default manager ( `objects` )  or add extra manager methods (which are not present in default manager).

So, if you can use the default manager without having to modify it then why reinventing the wheel.